# How to connect my API Gateway to HTTP endpoint on my EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, api-gateway

I'm trying to configure a API Gateway to HTTP connection to my EC2 instance that contain my endpoints

[image]

when I'm testing my API Gateway resource routed to my EC2 instance, I got this error

```
Execution log for request 96ab43de-f966-4860-882c-c072d302a3aa
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : Starting execution for request: 96ab43de-f966-4860-882c-c072d302a3aa
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /v1/test
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : Method request path: {}
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : Method request query string: {}
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : Method request headers: {}
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : Method request body before transformations: 
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : Request validation succeeded for content type application/json
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address
Thu Nov 03 17:02:59 UTC 2022 : Method completed with status: 500
```

I've already try to connect through VPC Link, but I couldn't get a different status code, I can't use a Public IP to my EC2 instance, also I can access to my EC2 enpoint from postman wihtout problems just ussing my VPN

This is my VPC Link configuration, I don't know if should I try to use an VPC link for REST APIs

[image]

This is my settings when I use VPC link

[image]

Comment: You have to use VPC link, there is not another option if your EC2 instance has to be private. Show what you tried with VPC link if you need us to help you with that.

Comment: thanks, I found what I needed, just I had not setted the NLB at the EC2 instance, and never will get this data at the VPC link configuration